How to prevent 'exec zsh' from killing the zsh currently running background jobs?
With zsh running as the current shell of a terminal, with one or several sub-process jobs running 'under' that zsh shell, executing exec zsh from that shell kills all running background jobs.
Is this expected?   Does that mean that someone should never execute exec zsh when the zsh shell has unfinished sub-process/background jobs running?  Or is there something that can be done/configured to prevent that behaviour?
In a (sourced) script it would always be possible to check if there are any jobs running, and interactively one could print the number of running jobs in the zsh prompt to make the user aware.  Are these the only possibilities?

How are you determining that they were killed? If you expect them to still show up in the job table... well, it's normal that they won't, but that doesn't mean they were killed -- it just means the new shell that took over the PID of the old one doesn't know about the children it inherited.

Which is to say -- look in ps, not in jobs, to see if the old children are running.

The jobs were terminal-based Emacs running in that shell that ran and that I suspended with suspend-frame.  I monitored the entire process tree with htop.  Typing just 'zsh' creates a sub-shell and I can see all are alive and I can see the jobs back when I exit from that sub-shell.  I'm also printing the jobs count in the zsh prompt.

The job count doesn't know about jobs created by the old shell; they exist, but the new shell inheriting the old shell's process table entry has no way of knowing that. Use ps for this instead.

If you want to get your copy of emacs back to the foreground, I'd try passing kill -CONT its PID. And in the future, maybe don't do the exec zsh trick without a good reason.

(btw, Stack Overflow is more focused on software development than interactive use -- questions about issues writing scripts are best placed here, questions about using interactive shells are best placed over at our sister site [unix.se])

I can see the process running with ps.  In fact I see all the processes that are under the terminal.  This means I first need to identify the right one and pick that one.  And if I want to show the sub-processes of that specific terminal I have to find the proper option. Looking....

Ok, will keep that in mind.  I should also have said it was for controlling a zsh prompt and some commands that control them, but the issue is simpler to explain that way...

I tried restoring that Emacs session (which did not hold anything - it was just a test) with kill -CONT or various fg commands without success.  I should also have said that these are tested on macOS, but I'v also tested on Linux with  the same results.

If you repro this on Linux, you might strace the process while you send it a SIGCONT. I suspect it might be successfully restarted but then, as soon as it tries to read input or change terminal settings, getting SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU signals (telling it that the terminal hasn't been handed off to it), but if that's the case I honestly don't have an immediate offhand suggested fix -- worthy question of itself.

I tried again on Linux, with Emacs 29.2 I got via apt-get (not built myself) in a new environment I'm setting.  I did a strace on the Emacs process 'hidden' after a exec zsh.  I can see the signals but Emacs does not react. Id need to build Emacs from source, and look more into it.  I'll have to do that later.

The premise is false: exec zsh doesn't kill background jobs.
However, job control is tracked inside the shell's memory, not provided by a call to the OS, so when you use exec zsh to replace the shell with a new instance (inheriting the old shell's process table entry, file descriptors and environment variables but losing most other state), that new instance doesn't know about jobs the old shell created.
Use tools like ps when you need to see previously-created background tasks whether or not your shell's job control is aware of them.
> sleep 60 & echo $!; exec zsh
[1] 33264
33264
> ps | grep 33264
33264 ttys002    0:00.01 sleep 60
33267 ttys002    0:00.00 grep 33264

